# Azure Kubernetes cluster creation stuck in "This size is currently unavailable in this location for this subscription"

Tags: azure, kubernetes

I am trying to create an Azure Kubernetes Cluster, i.e. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/

Upon going to the interface to create the cluster, I cannot create it because I get this error constantly:
[image]

Now, obviously what I have tried is to select different regions, and double check my subscription which otherwise seems correct and works fine for other resources. I also tried to create a different subscription with another credit card and still get the same error. I tried all the regions selectables.

Any idea what the problem is?

Comment: "This size is currently unavailable in this location for this subscription."
Read: The service you are trying to create is not available for your account in the East US region.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This unfortunately is a fairly common issue currently. As you may expect, there has been significant demand for Azure services over the last few weeks (up over 700%) and so some regions are suffering capacity issues. At this time the European regions seem to be hit the hardest. See this article for more information https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/update-2-on-microsoft-cloud-services-continuity/

The only solution currently is to retry, try other regions and other machine SKU;s. Based on that article we should see more capacity soon hopefully.

Comment: As said, I tried ALL regions. Same result.

Comment: Then it is likely that there are no VMs of that size available for your subscription. Note that the Dv2 is probably the worst size to try now, as these are older and have less capacity, try a DV3 or v4

Comment: Yes, it seems is the case. I think is the reason. 
Side question: Do you know if AWS is in the same situation?

Comment: I do not I'm afraid, I don't use much AWS

Comment: It seems that Azure is the only cloud provider now that is limiting new machines. I'm also trying to setup a European server, no luck. Works on Google and AWS.